# Can I use asymmetric encryption with AWS KMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-kms

I was wondering if I can use AWS KMS with such a use case. I want KMS to decrypt data sent over my an on-prem system (so no KMS). I was hoping that KMS can store the secret key. The on-prem system will use the public key to encrypt the data. Is this a feasible way?

From what I read so far KMS uses symmetric encryption? I can do what I want by using KMS to encrypt/decrypt my secret key, but the downside there is my app will have the secret key in plain text when using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

AWS KMS now supports asymmetric keys.

**Original answer:**

AWS KMS is for symmetric encryption only. There is no way to use KMS with asymmetric cryptography.

If you need this kind of functionality, you can use [CloudHSM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/crypto/latest/userguide/awscryp-service-hsm.html) instead of KMS.

Comment: Ok just learnt that yesterday too ... but it seems extremely expensive

Comment: Well, it is HSM after all. This stuff is expensive in general. Not to mention that now you only have to pay hourly fee, but few years ago, you would have to pay a huge amount of cash just to provision in.

Answer (score 1):

[AWS KMS](https://aws.amazon.com/kms/faqs/) supports the following asymmetric key types - RSA 2048, RSA 3072, RSA 4096, ECC NIST P-256, ECC NIST P-384, ECC NIST-521, and ECC SECG P-256k1.